# Porque no puedo eliminar un objeto de una lista en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Presento mi código:

```
numbers = list(range(0, 30, 2))
for i in range(0, 30):
    if numbers[i] % 2 == 0 and numbers[i] == 2:
        numbers[i] = 2 
    if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
        numbers.remove(i)
print(numbers)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python/list.", line 7, in <module>
    numbers.remove(i)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Alvaro, agrega mas detalles, que ocurre con este codigo, recibes algun error?

Comment: Agregalo a tu pregunta, de lo contrario sera cerrada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero en tu lista estás declarando el rango 0-30 con step de 2, es decir, estos tres parámetros:

> start: Empieza el número de la secuencia
>
> stop: Genera números hasta, pero no incluye este número
>
> step: Diferencia entre cada número de la secuencia

Por lo tanto, tu le estás indicando que haya una diferencia entre cada número de dos, lo que serían 15 números. Sin embargo, como el último (el 30), no lo incluye, en este caso serían 14 números.

El primer error que veo en tu código es que el bucle que estás realizando lo estás haciendo desde 0 hasta 29 y por lo tanto habrá posiciones para `numbers[i]` que no existirán.

Por otro lado, le estás intentado borrar un elemento que no existe en tu lista. Si te fijas, tu le estás asignando todo el rato el valor 2 a los elementos en los que incluyes algo. Sin embargo, estas intentando borrar un valor que no existe (1, 2, 3, 4...) ya que tu lista solamente está compuesta de números 2 y tu estás intentado borrar los valores del iterador, los cuales en este caso no almacenas en tu lista y por lo tanto no puede borrar.

Comment: vale vale, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

creo que el problema esta en lo siguiente:

```
>>>list(range(0,30,2))
```

soltara una lista con los siguientes items:

```
>>>[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28]
```

eso es lo que esta almacenado en tu lista. Son solo 15 numeros todos pares. El `for i in range (0,30)` tiene en cuenta elementos que no son pares : (0,1,2,3...29). Entonces tu error está en que le pides que remueva el indice cuando este no es par.

te doy un ejemplo clarificador: en la primer iteración el indice es 0; cuando llegue al punto de `numbers.remove(i)`; i valdra 0. Por ser el índice; casualmente también es el primer item de tu lista. Sin embargo en la segunda iteracion; i toma el valor 1; numbers[1] tiene asignado el valor dos, el cual segun tu codigo entra en el bloque:

```
if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
        numbers.remove(i)
```

pero.. ¿como va a remover al valor 1? ese numero no esta en la lista.
Espero que te haya servido esta explicación. Saludos.